# Facebook Pixel isn't receiving events optimized for iOS 14.5+

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

In trying to connect a Facebook Pixel and my Facebook catalogue, I'm receiving the following error:

---

Pixel isn't receiving events optimized for iOS 14.5+

Delivery or reporting may be reduced for people who opt out of tracking on iOS 14.5 or later devices because this pixel isn't receiving any events configured for iOS 14.5+ ad optimization. You may want to configure this pixel's events in Events Manager.

---

I can't find any documentation regarding what this means and how to fix this. Has anyone experienced this issue and have any suggestions on how to fix it?